# How to get the negative binary number of a positive number

Tags: python, string, binary, int

Given a positive number, I am trying to print a string that represents it's negative binary number.

I am doing something like this:

```
def NegativeBinary(number):

    number_below = number - 1
    bin_number_below = "{0:b}".format(number_below)

    # how can I invert this bin_number_below  afterwards, 
    # so that I return the negative of the number I got as an argument

    return bin_negative_number
```

In wish I subtract the number given for one, because it's negative binary number is basically the binary representation of number-1, with zeros and ones inverted.

ex :

```
num = NegativeBinary(5)
print(num)


**** output ****

In[1]:  '1011'
```

I am aware of the fact, that since I'm working with strings this might be a bit "trickier", however I'd be very grateful if anyone gave me an ideia on how to do this.

Comment: Are you assuming two complements and the minimum amount of bytes necessary to represent the int ?

Comment: yes, what I want to do is represent the negative number with minimum amount of bits necessary in this case. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: @Mark solution should work

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `number_below = -number`, and it should do what you want it to do. If you subtract one, then you are only subtracting one.

Comment: Hi Mark! I already tried that, but the result I get is just the regular binary number with "-" before it. For example `x = "{0:b}".format(-5) // x = '-101' ` , which is not exactly what I want